# Initialising swift view controller with nib name in objc class

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

In my app I have a view controller written in Swift. I imported it in to app delegate which is written in objective c. I try to create an object of the swift view controller like this

```
ListAllSongsViewController *songListVC = [[ListAllSongsViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ListAllSongsViewController" bundle:nil];
```

The `ListAllSongsViewController` is written in swift. The project compile without any issue but when executing the above line the app crashes & stops at init method of `ListAllSongsViewController`

[image: The crash]

There is nothing in the log, it just stops. Zombie & All exception break points are enabled.

P.S. It only crashes in device (iOS 7.1), but works fine in simulator

> **Update :** 
>   Getting the same issue even if I use the default swift initialiser
>
> ```
> ListAllSongsViewController(nibName: "ListAllSongsViewController", bundle: nil)
> ```

Comment: If you just use `alloc init` it will search for a nib with the same name and use that to instantiate the view controller. Try giving the nib the same name and just using `alloc init` instead.

Comment: @Fogmeister I tried that. It didn't work, got the same issue. Can we run swift app in iPhone 4 with iOS 7?

Answer (score 1):

Usually occurs when you passed a wrong `nibName`. Considering it crashes only in device, I think you've made a mistake about the case of the string `ListAllSongs`, because the Mac/Simulator's file system is case insensitive while the device is not.

Comment: thanks for the response. I tried all the basic testing, e.g. creating new VC with different names & xib names.